# ASP.net MVC - Passing an Id into a Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following route in my MVC application:

/foobars/edit/{id}

The {id} in this case corresponds to the Id for my "Foobar" model.

In my Edit view I am doing the following:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Notes/CreateNotePartial.cshtml", new CreateNoteViewModel())
```

The CreateNotePartial view uses a jQuery dialog and will POST to my NotesController using the following route:

/notes/create/{id}

The {id} in this case is NOT the same id as my Foobar id. My Foobar model has another property called UniqueId. I need to be able to pass this into my Partial view so that when I create the form to POST to the notes controller it passes in the right id.  What is the best way to do this?

Right now I am doing the following:

```
// Foobar Edit View
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Notes/CreateNotePartial.cshtml", new CreateNoteViewModel(Model.UniqueId))

// Create Note Partial
@model CreateNoteModel

@using( Html.BeginForm("Create", "Notes", FormMethod.Post, new { id = Model.UniqueId }) ) {
}
```

Is there a better way to pass this to my partial view or is this the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the best way to do it to me - I think your only other option is to pass it in `ViewData`, which everyone would tell you is not recommended for reasons of strong typing, magic strings, et al.

Certainly, it's the way that I do it (not that I'm the world's greatest authority of course).

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like, you're setting the form id to the model.UniqeId. That's just going to set the form's html element to whatever that model id is. I would not recommend doing that.

There's nothing wrong with using TempData (not the same as ViewData). TempData is made for passing a value from one view to another and then once it's accessed, it goes away. See [this post](http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications) for more.